# What is the difference between ()=>any and {():any} in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Now there is no error with this code and Typescript compiler consider it to be perfectly valid but are they the same? Can someone explain what is the difference between this 2 type definitions as well as give good use case examples for each one of them.

```
const b = () =>'hello'

const x: ()=>string = b
const y: {():string} = b
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are the same.

The second form does give you the option to add additional static properties if you want.

```
type FunctionWithId = {
    (): string;
    id: number;
}

const b = () => 'hello'
b.id = 4;
const x: FunctionWithId = b
```

It's also possible to use the second version to do function overloading:

```
type Example = {
  (x: number): number;
  (x: string): string;
}
```

So if you need some of those extra capabilities, use the second syntax. If not, either's fine, and you'll probably see the first one more often since it's simpler.

Comment: btw, function overloading on the first form looks like `((x: number) => number) & ((x: string) => string)`.